# Reading D70A weighing data from serial COM port with Java

Tags: java, javafx, serial-port, com-port

I want to read data from the scale and print it on the label with JavaFX. I made all the settings according to the documentation, but I cannot read the data. comPort.readBytes() always returns 0. Does anyone have any ideas about this? I am adding the document as a URL. I am working with cb string RS232.
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2121484/Bilanciai-D70e.html?page=51#manual

```java
package com.togisoft.venetacollaudipeso;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager;

import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class AppController {
    private SerialPort comPort;

    @FXML
    private Label weightLabel;


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        // COM Portunu bul ver aç
        comPort = SerialPort.getCommPort(Helper.getComPort());
        comPort.setNumDataBits(7);
        comPort.setBaudRate(Helper.getBaudRate());
        comPort.setParity(Helper.getComParity());
        comPort.setNumStopBits(Helper.getStopBit());
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        if (comPort.openPort()) {
            System.out.println("Port başarıyla açıldı.");

            executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::readFromSerial, 0, 300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Port açılırken hata oluştu!.");
            Platform.runLater(() -> weightLabel.setText("PORT Errore!"));
        }

    }

    private void readFromSerial() {
        while (comPort.isOpen()) {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[8];
            int numRead = comPort.readBytes(readBuffer, readBuffer.length);
            if (numRead > 0) {
                StringBuilder receivedData = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < numRead; i++) {
                    // Son biti (en anlamsız biti) düşürerek 7 bitlik veriyi elde et
                    int sevenBitData = readBuffer[i] & 0x7F;
                    receivedData.append((char) sevenBitData); // Veriyi String olarak birleştir
                }
                String weight = extractWeightFromData(receivedData.toString());
                updateUIWithWeight(formatWeight(weight));
            }
        }
    }

    private String formatWeight(String weightData) {
        if (weightData == null || !weightData.contains(".")) {
            return "0.0";
        }

        int significantDigits = 0;
        for (char c : weightData.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                significantDigits++;
            }
        }

        if (significantDigits >= 5) {
            try {
                float weight = Float.parseFloat(weightData);
                if (weight == (int) weight) {
                    // Ondalık kısmı sıfır ise, ondalık kısmı gösterme
                    return String.format("%.0f", weight);
                } else {
                    // Ondalık kısmı sıfırdan farklı ise, ondalık kısmı göster
                    return String.format("%.1f", weight);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());// Hata durumunda işlemler
            }
        }

        return "0.0"; // Varsayılan olarak 0 döndür
    }


    private String extractWeightFromData(String data) {
        if (data.length() >= 8 && data.startsWith("$(24H")) {
            return data.substring(2, 7); // 3–7 karakterleri alarak ağırlık bilgisini çıkar
        }
        return "";
    }

    private void updateUIWithWeight(String weight) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> weightLabel.setText(weight));
    }


    @FXML
    void onStamp() {
        System.out.println(weightLabel.getText());
        try {
            String sourceFileName = "weight.jasper";

            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("kilo", weightLabel.getText() + " KG"); // Örnek parametre

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sourceFileName, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

            PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
            PrintService selectedPrintService = null;
            for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
                if (printService.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Helper.getPrinter())) {
                    selectedPrintService = printService;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (selectedPrintService != null) {
                JasperPrintManager.printReport(print, false);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Belirtilen yazıcı bulunamadı.");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void onEnterPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            System.out.println("Enter pressed");
            onStamp();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        if (comPort != null && comPort.isOpen()) {
            comPort.closePort();
            System.out.println("Port closed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem (at the moment) is only with communicating with the com port correctly. That has nothing to do with JavaFX or Jasper reports.  Create a standalone class with a main method (a [mcve]) which just communicates with the com port and test that.  When in doubt consult the documentation for your device and [the serial communication library you are using](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/), including the provided examples.

Comment: After finding the weight from the Serial Port, I use a Jasper report to print from the printer.

Comment: Yes, but your issue is that you can’t read the weight from the serial port, not with using Jasper reports to print to a printer.  Better to keep questions focused.  Context can help, but not so much in this case.